# Java Synchronized method call but FIFO

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized, fifo, method-call

I want to call a method in java but synchronized and first-in-first-out.
Currently I call the method like so:

```
synchronized (synchronizeObject) {
     executeMethode(object1, object2);
}
```

I found out, that synchronized does not actually care in what order something is added.
Is there an easy way to force FIFO?

I do not think ArrayBlockingQueue is applicable here, At least not in a way I see it, but I may be wrong

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, you're right that synchronized doesn't have an order, but I'm not sure what you mean with _"something is added"_ in this context. An `ArrayBlockingQueue` or a `SynchronousQueue` might be what you need, but without more details on what you're trying to achieve, that is hard to guess at. An executor from `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` might also be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet:

```
public class AppTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        FairLockedMethod<Integer> method = new FairLockedMethod<>() {
            @Override
            protected void lockedMethod(Integer i) {
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            int n = i;
            pool.submit(() ->method.run(n));
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static abstract class FairLockedMethod<T> {

        protected abstract void lockedMethod(T value);

        private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        private final Queue<Thread> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

        public void run(T value) {
            queue.offer(Thread.currentThread());
            lock.lock();
            try {

                while (queue.peek() != Thread.currentThread()) {
                    condition.await();
                }
                queue.poll();
                condition.signalAll();
                lockedMethod(value);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not most efficient implementation, but simplest I can come with.